# KVO mechanism between two UIViewControllers in the UITABViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am new to iPhone. I am trying to implement KVO mechanism.

**What I have?**

two TabController with two UIViewController, FirstViewController has a button, 
SecondViewController has a UITextView

**What I Want?**

When button is pressed in the firstViewController, it updates member variable, which should be observed by secondViewController, and it should append to the UITextView.

**What I did?**

FirstViewController.h

```
@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController
{
    IBOutlet UIButton *submitButton;

}

-(IBAction)submitButtonPressed;

@property (retain) NSString* logString;
@end
```

FirstViewController.m

```
-(IBAction)submitButtonPressed
{
    NSLog (@" Submit Button PRessed ");
    self.logString = @"... BUtton PRessed and passing this information ";
}
```

SecondViewController.h

```
@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController
{
    IBOutlet UITextView *logView;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) UITextView *logView;
@end
```

SecondViewController.m

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
  ......

  NSArray *vControllers =     [self.tabBarController  viewControllers];
    FirstViewController *fvc = [vControllers objectAtIndex:0];
    [fvc addObserver:self  forKeyPath:@"logString" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:NULL];

  return self;
}


-(void) observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
    NSLog (@".... OBSERVE VALUE FOR KEY PATH...");    
}
```

**What output I Expect?**

The String ".... OBSERVE VALUE FOR KEY PATH..." should be printed each time i press the button in the FirstViewController.

**What I get?**

No OUtput.

**What i am doing wrong?. Kindly help me**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

put your "member variable" into a separate class file ... i.e. MODEL / view / controller.  Make a singleton model object holding your data, then you can KVO that model object from any view controller.

This is roughed out pseudo-code:

```
    @interface MyDataModel: NSObject
    {
     NSString *logString;
    }
    @property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *logString;
    @end

    @implementation MyDataModel

    @synthesize logString;

    + (MyDataModel *) modelObject
    {
     static MyDataModel *instance = nil;
     static dispatch_once_t once;
     dispatch_once(&once, ^{
       if (instance == nil)
       {
        instance = [[self alloc] init];
       }
     });

     return (instance);
    }

    @end
```

in your VC1

```
MyDataModel *model = [MyDataModel modelObject];
[model setLogString:@"test"];
```

in your VC2

```
[model addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"logString" options:0 context:NULL];
```

a more sophisticated approach would use Core Data as a persistent store and to act as your data model.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I m very much new into ios. Would you mind providing few more information so that i can dig more into it?

Comment: edited answer to show some roughed out code to get you heading in the right direction

Comment: as for the static `instance`, is its pointer always the same? Since it's a singleton?

Comment: [alloc init] is called once, after which the value of instance won't change.  Consider putting the initialization code into a dispatch_once block, I'll edit the answer to show how to do this